# Underscore findWhere function to find element match condition a or b

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects

```
var arr = [{a:1},{a:5}, {a:6},{a:11}];
```

I want to use underscore find where function to retrieve object satisfying condition `a = 1` or `a =11`

**like:**

```
_findWhere(arr, {a:1} || {a:11})
```

Anything like this is possible ??

Answer (score 8):

[**find**](http://underscorejs.org/#find) behaves like findWhere in that it returns the first item that passes the search criteria. With find you can use a predicate to specify the search criteria.

```
var result = _.find(arr, function(item) {
    return item.a == 1 || item.a == 11;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use _.filter for this

```
var arr = [{a:1}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:11}];
_.filter(arr,function(n){return (n.a===1 || n.a===11)});
```

But there is a better solution which can help you adding as many or as you want. Using _.mixin you can create your own or function

```
var arr = [{a:1}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:11}];
_.mixin({
   or: function(obj,arr,condition){
     return _.chain(arr).where(condition).union(obj).value();
   }
});

_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11}).or(arr,{a:2}).value();//returns 2 objects
_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11}).or(arr,{a:5}).value();//returns 3 objects
_.chain(arr).where({a:1}).or(arr,{a:11}).value();//returns 2 objects

var arr2 = [{a:1,b:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:11}];
_.chain(arr2).where({a:1}).or(arr2,{a:11}).value();//returns 2 objects
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in plain Javascript with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 11 }, { a: 11 }],
    found = function (array) {
        var index;
        return arr.some(function (a, i) {
            if (a.a === 1 || a.a === 11) {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
        }) && array[index] || undefined;
    }(arr);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(found, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `find` != `filter`

Comment: Nina your result is still an array, but it needs to be the first one element that passes a truth test.

Comment: @isvforall, i understand now.

Answer (score 1):

For your case better to use `find` function. You can use function that passed as a second argument to `find` method and checks your two conditions:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 11 }];

var elem = _.find(arr, function(e) {
    return e.a == 1 || e.a == 11;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(elem));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

---

Or using plain javascript (`ES2015`):

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 11 }];

var elem = arr.find(function(e) {
    return e.a == 1 || e.a == 11;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(elem));
```

Comment: findWhere doesn't take a function. If you change arr so that the first object is something like {a: 77} then this will be returned by the first code snippet.